# Handling 3rd Party API Tokens in Node.js App

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest

Hey everyone I have a high level question regarding structuring node.js restful api's and utilizing 3rd party api's within them!

This is my proposed solution, although I'm not sure if this will work, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
Front-End (React Native App)
- communicates with back-end

Back-End  (Node.js Rest API)
- takes requests from front-end via endpoints 
- communicates with postgres for database
- communicates with 3rd party api (store token and fetch refresh token whenever expires, is this even possible?)
```

Now my confusion lies in the communication with the 3rd party api, for this example let's say Spotify. In order to utilize spotify api's I need an access token. No problem, however after I receive that token, is the rest api able to store that and use it for future calls? Or do I need to get a new auth token every time i want to utilize the api?

TL;DR: How does a node.js restful server keep up with 3rd party tokens and refresh tokens?

Comment: Yes, your back end needs to store the tokens and refresh tokens and re-request them when they expire, and store the updated values.

Comment: Look here for Spotify's example: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow

Comment: In Spotify's case, you first get your user to authorize your app. After they do that, it redirects to a place in your app that you can specify, with a 'code' in the query parameters. Pull that code out, make a request to Spotify using that code to get a set of Access Token / Refresh Token for this user. At this point, you store those two values in a table connected to that user with an expiry date. Every time you want to use the Access Token, check if it's expired. If it has, use the Refresh Token to get a new Access / Refresh token and update those values in the table.